# Can't write new files, but can modify existing

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I've just set up a dokuwiki page on an apache2 server running on Ubuntu 16.04. When the dokuwiki tries to create a new page, I get a http 500 error (The IP page isn’t working. IP is currently unable to handle this request.). However, I can edit and save an existing page without problems.

I've looked at the list of things to fix https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:error500, but I'm not sure where to start. I'm not doing any pretty URL rewriting that I'm aware of. My .htaccess files look like:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_host>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_host>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

My bin, data, inc, lib, vendor, and conf folders are all drwxrwxr-x and owned by www-data.

Can someone please point me in the write direction?

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Thanks! That showed Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_decode() - so I'll start looking into that.

Comment: If you mix Require directives with old deprecated Order,Allow,Deny directives, you are in for big trouble. Use 2.4 Require directives only if you are using 2.4.

Comment: @ezra-s : It's not mixed, but the formatting was hiding the `<if` parts.

Answer (score 0):

`Call to undefined function utf8_decode()` means there's a crucial function missing in your PHP installation. On some distributions you need to install a php-xml package for the utf8_decode and utf8_encode methods.